# Found useful info on a post closed as "too narrow/restricted". Is that Ok?

Tags: discussion

It says "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, visit the help center.
Closed 10 years ago."

[How can systemd run a command as root before launching a service as a different user?](https://serverfault.com/questions/482319/how-can-systemd-run-a-command-as-root-before-launching-a-service-as-a-different)

However, I found useful-to-me information on running commands as root before starting a service running as a less-privileed user.

The OP wanted to create directories for subversion, and finds out about systemd tmpfiles.

But I found out about "ExecStartPre=+" which solved by usecase of firewall adjustment as root before launcing a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case please upvote the content. The close vote at that point is not important as the question was answered, and as it's upvoted it will never be erased by the roomba bot of StackExchange.

To sum it up; the question will stay on the site for historical reason as it defied the deletion's rules.

The roomba bot info there; [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)